# How to use Struts2 validation for conditional validation?

Tags: java, validation, struts2

Can Struts2 be used for conditional validation?  As in, if checkbox "Other" is filled in, then field "otherDetails" must not be empty?

Note that I'm looking for Struts2, not Struts1.  Any example is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You can probably use an expression validator. If you're validating via XML, you should have something like:

```
<validators>

  <validator type="expression">
    <param name="expression">(other && (otherDetails!=null && otherDetails.trim()!=""))</param>
    <message>You must provide other details.</message>
  </validator>

</validators>
```

See http://struts.apache.org/2.2.1/docs/validation.html for more info.

Answer (score 2):

You could maybe use JS validation.

JSP:

```
<s:checkbox id="other" name="other" />
<s:textfield id="otherDetails" name="otherDetails"></s:textfield>

<sx:submit 
            id="button_submit"
            name="button_submit"
            onclick="return checkOther();" />
```

JS:

```
function checkOther() {
    if(document.getElementById('other').checked == true) {
        if(document.getElementyById('otherDetails').value.length == 0) {
            //you should trim the value
            alert("Insert other details");
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `<sx:submit` or is that a typo?  +1 for general helpfulness, but I'll not accept it since I really want to know if struts validation can do this.

Comment: No, it's not a typo, it's Strutses Dojo tag. For struts validation I hope you'll get an asnwer.