# Struts2 conditional validation

Tags: validation, struts2

Is it possible in Struts 2 to avoid several validations (defined as anotations) depending on the value of a given field? Something like: "if radiobutton has value x do not validate fields a, b and c".

This would be useful to me since I'm developing a JSP page (model driven) and I'm not showing all the fields at the same time, the visible ones depend on a radiobutton value. However, when submiting, the validators from the hidden fields are "activated" and the validation process fails. So, I want to to ignore the hidden ones, is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: I think this question has been asked before.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553330/struts2-conditional-xml-validation or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329105/how-to-use-struts2-validation-for-conditional-validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do this using OGNL and the expression validator
[Apache Struts 2 Documentation](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/expression-validator.html)

I do this using xml because IMHO annotations are a bit intrusive, and rather not use them everywhere. But you sure can use the annotation version [Validation Annotation](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/validation-annotation.html).

Hope it helps...

Comment: You should notice that the Validation annotation is deprecated since Struts2 2.1 and now you can use any other validation annotation at the method level without using it...